# Address operator on big endian system

Tags: c, endianness

Many people know the following example to find out whether a system is little endian or big endian:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()  
{ 
   unsigned int i = 1; 
   char *c = (char*)&i; 
   if (*c)     
       printf("Little-endian"); 
   else
       printf("Big-endian"); 
   getchar(); 
   return 0; 
}
```

However, I would like to know whether the following piece of code is also still valid and functional:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   unsigned int i = 1;
   char *c = &i;
   if (*c)
       printf("Little-endian");
   else
       printf("Big-endian");
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

I want to ask whether the address of operator, &, works the same on both big-endian and little-endian systems. Will it in both cases point to the lowest addressed byte of the object when a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type?

My worry is the following. Suppose that you do not do the type conversion as above and also suppose a big-endian system returns you the highest bit address (basically where the int starts), then this piece of code will still print "Little-endian" although you are really dealing with a big-endian system.

Any comment on this would be really helpful. Thank you in advance :D.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: The only difference between the two code samples is the `(char*)` cast is missing from the second example.  Pretty sure that's there for a reason.

Comment: "This basically deals with the question on how the address operator, &, on big endian systems is interpreted." - it does not. It asks if an implicit conversion from an `int *` to a `char *` is done. It has nothing to do with the endianes of the system. Apparently, because the code also has to run on a little-endian system.

Comment: The address-of operator works the same on big endian and little endian systems, it get's the address of a variable.

Comment: You're not asking about the address operator, you're asking about the cast `(char*)`...

Answer (score 4):

The assignment `char *c = &i;` violates the constraints in C 2018 6.5.16.1 1. That paragraph says “One of the following shall hold,” and the closest match in the list of options is:

- the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

`char *` and `int *` are not compatible, so the assignment fails the constraints.

That said, if the compiler did accept this statement (which it may, since the C standard permits extensions) and converts the pointer on the right to the type on the left (as assignments should), the result should be a pointer to the lowest addressed byte of the object, regardless of endianness. This is normal for pointer conversions per C 2018 6.3.2.3 7:

> … When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer. My question was indeed whether I will receive lowest or highest address byte of the object depending on the endianness of the system, but as you state clearly over here that will not happen. You mention that this is the case per C 2018 6.3.2.3.7. Are there any (earlier) versions to be found where this conversion will result in a pointer to the highest addressed byte?

Comment: @Fatih: No, it has been that way forever. In C 1999, it is 6.3.2.3 8. (Note: There is a space, not a period, before the last number there. C is the (informal) name of the standard, 1999 is the year, 6.3.2.3 is the clause, and 8 is the paragraph. I cannot find my copy of the 1989 C standard (on paper), but I am sure it was the same way there and in pre-standard C.

Answer (score 0):

The second example will give you a compiler warning that the assignment is invalid without a casting.
If you ignore the warning, you might get the same result or not, as always when trying undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah, I see what the OP's code is doing now.  So yeah, you need that cast.

Comment: there is no difference between the two codes, other than one has an explicit cast the other an implicit one. If one is UB then the other is UB too. If one is valid then the other is valid too.

Comment: @bolov There is no such thing as an "implicit cast". A cast is an explicit type conversion.

Comment: It shouldn't be undefined because of the `char*` exception to the aliasing rules.